# cannot bind list object when enctype=multipart/form-data

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a **command class** that has a list object. I'm iterating through this object to have input text box on view like,

```
<c:forEach items="${addPizza.pizzaSizes}" var="siz">
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${siz.size}:" /></td>
        <td><input name="siz[${status.index}].sizes" value="${siz.size}" /></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

and I'm allowing user to edit the list and on submit I have updated list with my controller

```
<tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Save"></td></tr>
```

But now added a file input tag to browse image to the same view like ,

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file">
```

and set the form tag to `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

on doing this I'm getting list as null but I'm getting the image blob. And if I remove it I'm getting list but not image. How can I get both ?

Code snippet is as follows,

```
public class Command{

    List<Contact> contacts;
    blob image;
.....
}

Class Contact{
long id;
long name;
......
}

Controller{
.....
Blob blob=Hibernate.createBlob(file.getInputStream());
command.setImage(blob);
........
}
```

Thanks in adavance.

Comment: How does your command handle the multipart request (we need code)?

Comment: public class Command{

 List<Contact> contacts;
 blob image;
.....
}

Class Contact{
long id;
long name;
......
}

Controller{
.....
Blob blob=Hibernate.createBlob(file.getInputStream());
command.setImage(blob);
........
}

Comment: As I said - please provide the code (add it to your question).